# Laravel get current route path pattern

Tags: laravel, lumen

**Lumen route:**

```
+--------+---------------------------+------------+----------------------------------------------------+---------+--------------------------+
| Verb   | Path                      | NamedRoute | Controller                                         | Action  | Middleware               |
+--------+---------------------------+------------+----------------------------------------------------+---------+--------------------------+
| GET    | /                         |            | None                                               | Closure |                          |
| POST   | /login                    |            | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController           | login   |                          |
| GET    | /setting/menu             |            | App\Http\Controllers\Setting\MenuController        | index   | auth, auth.authorization |
| POST   | /setting/menu             |            | App\Http\Controllers\Setting\MenuController        | store   | auth, auth.authorization |
| GET    | /setting/menu/{id}        |            | App\Http\Controllers\Setting\MenuController        | show    | auth, auth.authorization |
| PUT    | /setting/menu/{id}        |            | App\Http\Controllers\Setting\MenuController        | update  | auth, auth.authorization |
| DELETE | /setting/menu/{id}        |            | App\Http\Controllers\Setting\MenuController        | destroy | auth, auth.authorization |
+--------+---------------------------+------------+----------------------------------------------------+---------+--------------------------+
```

`$request->route()` only return route name, How can I get the route path like `/setting/menu/{id}`?

> I used Lumen 9.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be desirable to obtain the parameterised path pattern for logging purposes on shutdown.

Here is a solution for Lumen/Laravel that will work in any situation, especially where the routes are not named (where `$request->route()[1]['as']` cannot be used)

```
class RouteUtils
{

    /**
     * Attempts to match a given request URI with the parameterized URL from route definitions.
     *
     * @param array $urlsWithPlaceholders The route definitions with curly braces for parameters.
     * These typically come from the app()->router->getRoutes() array
     * @param string $inputUrlWithValues The URL to match to the route definitions
     * @return array [url, params] where params is an associative array of the variable names and values
     */
    private static function uriToPath(array $urlsWithPlaceholders, string $inputUrlWithValues): array
    {
        // Remove any trailing slashes
        $inputUrlWithValues = rtrim($inputUrlWithValues, '/');

        // iterate over the parameterized URL definitions (each item is an array from app()->router->getRoutes())
        // (It's actually an associative array - the key name (not needed) is the path prefixed with the HTTP method)
        foreach ($urlsWithPlaceholders as $urlWithVariables) {
            // replace the variables enclosed in curly braces with a regular expression pattern
            $pattern = preg_replace('/\{[^}]+}/', '([^\/]+)', $urlWithVariables);

            // match the input URL with the pattern
            if (preg_match('#^' . $pattern . '$#', $inputUrlWithValues, $matches)) {
                // extract the variable values from the matched input URL
                $variableValues = array_slice($matches, 1);

                // extract the variable names from the URL with variables enclosed in curly braces
                preg_match_all('/\{([^}]+)}/', $urlWithVariables, $variableNames);
                $variableNames = $variableNames[1];

                // combine the variable names and values into an associative array
                $params = array_combine($variableNames, $variableValues);

                // set the result to the matched URL with the variable values
                return [
                    'path'   => $urlWithVariables,
                    'params' => $params
                ];
            }
        }

        return [
            'path'   => '',
            'params' => []
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Helper to get the current path pattern from the current request, 
     * with the original parameterized segments,
     * as efficiently as possible using filters and regex
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public static function getPathDefinition(): string
    {
        // Grab the request and the routes from Lumen
        $request     = app('request');
        $appRoutes   = app()->router->getRoutes();
        if (!$request && $appRoutes) return '';

        $reqMethod   = $request->method();
        $reqUri      = $request->getPathInfo(); // without the query string
        $reqSegments = count(explode('/', $reqUri)); // number of segments in the path

        // First shortlist the possible routes using simpler filters,
        // before applying the expensive regex. We'll avoid doing regex on every route.
        $shortList = [];
        foreach ($appRoutes as &$routeInfo) {
            // Skip routes with a different HTTP method
            if ($routeInfo['method'] !== $reqMethod) continue;

            // Skip routes with a different number of segments
            // $routeInfo['uri'] is the path as defined in the route file with curly braces for parameters
            if (count(explode('/', $routeInfo['uri'])) !== $reqSegments) continue;

            // Skip if first piece of the path before parameters doesn't match the current full request
            // Get everything before the first parameterized segment
            $pathPattern = ($lTrim = strstr($routeInfo['uri'], "/{", true)) !== false ? $lTrim : $routeInfo['uri'];
            if (!str_contains($reqUri, $pathPattern)) continue;

            // From here we've quickly narrowed down possible routes to a short list, probably within same controller
            // Usually this array will contain just 1 route. Much faster to apply the regex from here
            $shortList[] = $routeInfo['uri'];
        }
        // Always unset references when done with them
        unset($routeInfo);

        // Now try to match the exact request to the route including parameters
        $resultPath = self::uriToPath($shortList, $reqUri);
        return ($resultPath['path'] ?? '[unknown]');
    }

}
```

And use it like this

```
$currentPathPattern = RouteUtils::getPathDefinition();
```

Could also set it up as a "service provider"

```
class RouteUtilsProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register(): void
    {
        $this->app->bind('RouteUtils', function () {
            return new RouteUtils();
        });
    }

    // ...
```

If it's possible to do so, naming all of your paths with "as" will enable a faster solution

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```php
$request->path()
```

- Laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/requests#retrieving-the-request-path
- Lumen docs: https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/9.x/requests

Comment: I need the pattern of the path.

Comment: So, you want to get `/setting/menu/{id}` rather than `/setting/menu/1` ?

Comment: Yes! correct...

Answer (score 0):

you better name your route to make it easier for you, https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#named-routes.

like this

```
$router->get('setting/menu/{id}', ['as' => 'setting.menu.show', 'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\Setting\MenuController@show']);
$router->put('setting/menu/{id}', ['as' => 'setting.menu.update', 'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\Setting\MenuController@update']);
```

and then you can call

```
    $path = '';
    $routes = app()->router->getRoutes();
    $name = $request->route()[1]['as'];
    
    foreach ($routes as $key1 => $value1) {
        foreach ($value1 as $key2 => $value2) {
            if ( $key2 == 'action' ) {
                foreach ($value1[ $key2 ] as $key3 => $value3) {
                    if ( $key3 == 'as' ) {
                        if ( $value2[ $key3 ] == $name ) {
                            $path = $key1;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    dd($path); // result GET/setting/menu/{id}, you can remove get from string.
```

Comment: Seem accurate, but I found bug. It showing up `DELETE/pengaturan/menu/{id}` instead of `GET/setting/menu/{id}`

Comment: can you show latest route list? I suspect route naming is not correct.